# How to use ffmpeg to make an image round-corner?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to use ffmpeg to make an image round-corner? Can ffmpeg do this job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give a video rounded transparent edges so that it can be overlayed on another video using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859841/give-a-video-rounded-transparent-edges-so-that-it-can-be-overlayed-on-another-vi)

Answer (score 1):

For Video - [Give a video rounded transparent edges so that it can be overlayed on another video using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859841/give-a-video-rounded-transparent-edges-so-that-it-can-be-overlayed-on-another-vi)

For Image

> ffmpeg -i ${input} -update true -frames:v 1 -filter_complex "format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-${radius})*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-${radius}),if(lte(hypot(${radius}-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),${radius}-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),${radius}),255,0),255)'" ${output}

- ${input} - replace with input file path/url
- ${output} - replace with output file path
- ${radius} - replace with desired raidus of the circle (For more info see [video link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859841/give-a-video-rounded-transparent-edges-so-that-it-can-be-overlayed-on-another-vi))

Example

> ffmpeg -i https://www.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/338250266/display_1500/stock-vector-sample-red-square-grunge-stamp-on-white-sample-stamp-sample-sample-sign-338250266.jpg -update true -frames:v 1 -filter_complex "format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-200)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-200),if(lte(hypot(200-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),200-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),200),255,0),255)'" output.png

Comment: oh wow nice example

Answer (score -1):

No, ffmpeg can't do that.  Try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).  Note particularly `-clip-mask` and `roundedRectangle`.

Comment: Please put more descriptions and commands.