# Give a video rounded transparent edges so that it can be overlayed on another video using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Im trying to overlay a smaller video (200x200)on top of a bigger video (800x800).

I've used the FFMPEG overlay filter to achieve this

```
    ffmpeg -i big.mp4 -vf "movie=small.mkv[clip2]; [in][clip2] overlay=1:5 [out]"  final.mp4
```

Challenge is that the smaller video needs its edges to be rounded.
I have tried working with alphaextract and alphamerge. The documentation on FFMPEG is sparse and im not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 19):

Although I think the existing answer is good for a circle, it sounds like you wanted more of a “rounded rectangle” instead. Here is how I have done that:

```
[1]format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-10)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-10),if(lte(hypot(10-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),10-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),10),255,0),255)'[rounded];
```

About `format`:

The [alpha values can’t be changed in a source that doesn’t have an existing alpha channel](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-May/015374.html). So the `format=yuva420p` filter adds one (that is the `a` in `yuva`). From what I have seen, `yuva444p` is also common (used in [other answers](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/25073)), but other formats like `rgba` ought to work, provided they have an alpha channel. My original source was `yuv420p` so I made mine `yuva420p`.

About `geq`:

It seems you can’t change *only* the alpha channel (if you try, you’ll get an error “A luminance or RGB expression is mandatory”), so the `lum='p(X,Y)'` is basically a dummy no-op to allow you to change the alpha without changing anything else.

So that it’s not necessary to check each corner individually, X and Y are converted into the upper left quadrant by the formula:

```
X' = W/2-abs(W/2-X)
Y' = H/2-abs(H/2-Y)
```

The first part of the formula checks whether `X'` and `Y'` are within the thatched area:

[image: Upper left quadrant]

That is, whether:

```
    X' < 10
and Y' < 10
```

If they are not, `a` is set to `255` (ie, show the pixel).

If they fall within this area, the distance is calculated between the point `(X,Y)` and the centre of the circle at `(10,10)`. If the point `(X,Y)` falls within the circle, `a` is set to `255`; otherwise, `a` is set to `0`, and that pixel is hidden.

The radius can be changed to give more or less ‘rounding’. A full example command with a radius of `20` is:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=darkblue:size=800x600 -f lavfi -i color=gray:size=600x450 -frames:v 180 -filter_complex "[1]format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-20)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-20),if(lte(hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),20),255,0),255)'[rounded];[0][rounded]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" example.mp4
```

Giving the result:

[image: Example rounded rectangle video frame]

In my examples I have used `10` or `20` as the radius of the circle, but you can change this to any number to make the corners more or less rounded as you like.

Comment: Awesome!
For convenience, I've replaced your numbers for the border radii with a shell a variable:

`corner_radius=10`


`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=darkblue:size=800x600 -f lavfi -i color=gray:size=600x450 -frames:v 180 -filter_complex "[1]format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-${corner_radius})*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-${corner_radius}),if(lte(hypot(${corner_radius}-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),${corner_radius}-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),${corner_radius}),255,0),255)'[rounded];[0][rounded]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" example.mp4`

Comment: Awesome as well! Is there anything I can do to have better rounding corners?

Comment: Define ‘better’, please. :-)
You could try a different value for the radius. If you don’t like the quarter-circle arc at all, you could draw your own curve and figure out how to express it as a formula, then adapt the above to use it.

Comment: If your round corners are to jagged (aliased), you could initially make the size twice as big ( "... color=gray:size=1200x900 ..." ), then run the "geq" on this bigger canvas and finally scale it back. Then the round corners would be anti-aliased and appear smoother. (However in this case it might be better to use a percentage value for your round corner.)

Answer (score 3):

[Main movie](http://mirror.cessen.com/blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_iphone.m4v) with circular shaped overlay ([2nd movie](https://download.blender.org/durian/trailer/sintel_trailer-480p.mp4))
[image: Result]

```
ffmpeg \
-i "trailer_iphone.m4v" \
-i "sintel_trailer-480p.mp4" \
-filter_complex "\
[1]format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)'[circular shaped video];\
[circular shaped video]scale=w=-1:h=200[circular shaped video small];\
[0][circular shaped video small]overlay" \
-filter_complex_threads 1 \
-map 0:a \
-metadata:s:a:0 title="Sound main movie" \
-disposition:a:0 default \
-map 1:a \
-metadata:s:a:1 title="Sound overlayed movie" \
-disposition:a:1 none \
-c:v libx264 \
-preset ultrafast \
-shortest \
"result.mp4"
```

Explanation:

Line 5: To create a circular mask we use the "geq" filter. This is used to create circular shaped video with alpha channel from 2nd video input

Line 6: scale height of circular shaped video to 200px, preserve aspect ratio

Line 7: overlay video

Line 8: [Gyan](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/1871/gyan) came up with this solution for the geq filter [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/25073/24237).

You can skip Lines 9 - 14. Then ffmpeg will default to use the Audio track of the main movie.

*Line 9: optional: Audio of the 1st input will be 1st Audio track in the output*

*Line 10: optional: give 1st Audio track in the output a name (works in VLC)*

*Line 11: optional: make sure that 1st Audio track in the output will be played as the default track*

*Line 12: optional: Audio of the 2nd input will be 2nd Audio track in the output*

*Line 13: optional: give 2nd Audio track in the output a name (works in VLC)*

*Line 14: optional: make sure that 2nd Audio track in the output will not be played unless you choose it with the player (VLC)*

Line 17: duration of the output will be as long as the shortest input