# ffmpeg - overlay a video with rounded corners

Tags: ffmpeg

I am successfully using overlaying a scaled (smaller) video on top of a larger one but am struggling to understand how could I give the small video a rounded corners mask.

**Edit**

thanks to @loogan comment I've managed to get a working command that created applies a circular mask :

```
ffmpeg 
    -i main.mp4 
    -i vignette.mp4 
    -filter_complex 
      [1:v]scale=300:-1[scaled];
      [scaled]split [scaled0][scaled11]; 
      [scaled0]trim=end_frame=1,geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),780*780),255,0)':3:3,loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];
    [scaled1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];
    [0][cutout]overlay=x=W-w:y=0[v];
    -map [v] 
    -map [a]  
    output.mp4
```

but how to get from a circle to a rounded rect still eludes me. cant quite get what are the params that geq expects and the math to generate them.

assuming that the video that needs masking is 200 * 300 and the corners should have a 5px radius, is there a geq command that can create this mask ? maybe en ellipse ?

or maybe a better way would be to use a pre-made png as a mask ?

any insights welcome

Comment: `[scaled]` was already consumed so use split filter if you want to make multiples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Give a video rounded transparent edges so that it can be overlayed on another video using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859841/give-a-video-rounded-transparent-edges-so-that-it-can-be-overlayed-on-another-vi)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy method is to use the [vignette](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vignette) filter:

[image: vignette mask]
<sub>Example vignette mask</sub>

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i vignette.mp4 -filter_complex "color=c=white,vignette=angle=PI/2:aspect=4/3[mask];[1][mask]alphamerge[fg];[2][fg]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Adjust `angle` and `aspect`.