# How create a circular video (transparent area on top of video) effect without applying image mask to video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mask

Basically i googled a lot and solutions suggests apply some PNG mask or do not provide needed solution.

What i've found.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -i facecloseup.mkv
 -filter_complex "[1]trim=end_frame=1,
  geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':128:128,
  loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];
  [1][mask]alphamerge[cutout];
  [0][cutout]overlay=x=W-w:y=0[v];
  [0][1]amix=2[a]"
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  out.mp4
```

```
command = "-i " + this.video1Path.getPath() + " -i " + this.video2Path.getPath() + " -filter_complex [1]trim=end_frame=1,geq=lum_expr='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3)," + (this.mZoomLayout.getZoomedWidth()/2) + "*" + (this.mZoomLayout.getZoomedWidth()/2) + "),255,0)':128:128,format=gray,loop=-1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[mask];[1][mask]alphamerge,format=rgba,lutrgb=a=if(gte(val\\,16)\\,val)[cutout];[0][cutout]overlay=" + this.mZoomLayout.getCircleX() + ":" + this.mZoomLayout.getCircleY() + ":enable='between(t,0," + this.videoTwoDuration + ") -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast " + videoPath.getPath();
```

So i tried to extract needed things from them, but i don't understand how exactly i need to do that, i did this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':H:W; [0:v][mask]alphamerge" out.mp4
```

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001f761dd8e40] Invalid stream specifier: mask.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'mask' in filtergraph description [0]geq='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':H:W; [0:v][mask]alphamerge matches no streams.
```

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]geq=lum_expr='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':H:W; [0:v][mask]alphamerge" out.mp4
```

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001bfd9218e80] Invalid stream specifier: mask.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'mask' in filtergraph description [0]geq=lum_expr='st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),pow(min(W/2,H/2),2)),255,0)':H:W; [0:v][mask]alphamerge matches no streams.
```

And one more time, guys, if you are going to post some "prepared image mask" solution - just leave, the question is about creating mask on air.

So, let's say we have red square (yes, ratio is static, always 1:1), yes, i can't post it because i dont have 10 rep. (...).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsL71.png - red square.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIFEV.png - circle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8EAx.png - result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtqQg.png - final result

I actually want to get the answer from @Gyan or @llogan because i searched a lot and only these two guys do understand how to make things programmatically.

More tech details:
Aspect ratio is constant - 1:1, width and height should be taken from the video in auto way, we need to create a white square with transparent circle inside it, the end result must contain "rounded" video with white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate your "**final result**" with this images:

- [red.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdkfo.png)
- [blue.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatHx.png)

### 2 inputs

[image: red vignette over blue circle]

The value of the `height` variable should match the height of your source files. In this case it's 600px.

```
red="red.png"
blue="blue.png"

height=600

ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -i "${red}" \
-loop 1 -i "${blue}" \
-filter_complex "\
[1]format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)'[circular shaped video];\
[circular shaped video]scale=w=-1:h=${height}[circular shaped video small];\
[0][circular shaped video small]overlay" \
-filter_complex_threads 1 \
-c:v libx264 \
-preset ultrafast \
-t 5 \
"final_result.mp4"
```

You only need the `-loop 1` options in front of the input when using images.

If you are using video you might decide which audio to use.

You can see everything in detail in my original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58595644/6444590).

### 1 input only

[image: red vignette over blue circle]

Here you only have to choose the color of the circular vignette.

Color names are listet in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color).

```
in="blue.png"

vignette_color="red"

ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -i "${in}" \
-filter_complex "\
[0]setsar=1:1,format=yuva444p,drawbox=color=${vignette_color}@1:t=fill[vignette];\
[0]format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)'[circular shaped video];\
[vignette][circular shaped video]overlay" \
-filter_complex_threads 1 \
-c:v libx264 \
-preset ultrafast \
-t 5 \
"result.mp4"
```

### 1 video auto squared

audio included. Anti-aliasing vignette edges.

[image]

```
in="snowboarder.mp4"

vignette_color="black"

# edge of vignette can be jagged. 
# use value between 1 - 2 (e.g. 1.2). 1 doesn't do anything.
anti_aliasing=2

ffmpeg \
-i "${in}" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]crop=ih:ih[video square];[video square]split=2[video square 1][video square 2];\
[video square 1]setsar=1:1,drawbox=color=${vignette_color}@1:t=fill[vignette];\
[video square 2]scale=w=iw*"${anti_aliasing}":h=iw*"${anti_aliasing}",format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)'[scaled up circular shaped video];\
[scaled up circular shaped video]scale=w=iw/"${anti_aliasing}":h=iw/"${anti_aliasing}"[circular shaped video];\
[vignette][circular shaped video]overlay" \
-filter_complex_threads 1 \
-c:v libx264 \
-c:a aac \
-preset ultrafast \
"result_square.mp4"
```

### round video (square video with transparency)

[image: webm video with alpha channel in Firefox browser]

Chrome and Firefox support WebM videos with transparency (alpha channels).

The checkerboard pattern is not part of the video. It is the background.

```
in="snowboarder.mp4"

# edge of vignette can be jagged. 
# use value between 1 - 2 (e.g. 1.2). 1 doesn't do anything.
anti_aliasing=2    

ffmpeg \
-i "${i}" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]crop=ih:ih[video square];\
[video square]split=3[black canvas][white canvas][video square];\
[black canvas]setsar=1:1,drawbox=color=black@1:t=fill[black background];\
[white canvas]scale=w=iw*"${anti_aliasing}":h=iw*"${anti_aliasing}",format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)',drawbox=color=white@1:t=fill[scaled up white circle];\
[scaled up white circle]scale=w=iw/"${anti_aliasing}":h=iw/"${anti_aliasing}"[white circle];\
[black background][white circle]overlay[alpha mask];\
[video square][alpha mask]alphamerge,format=yuva420p" \
-filter_complex_threads 1 \
-c:v libvpx -auto-alt-ref 0 \
-c:a libvorbis \
-preset ultrafast \
"result_square.webm"
```

Comment: Ok, interesting. Images were posted just an example, the only one thing that i have is one video file and i need to draw squared mask on top. In your current solution there is still 2 layers, but ill try it, ok. So, i need to create that "squared and circled mask" on air and apply it. https://i.imgur.com/DSwQGNY.png this part is what i need from code that you posted in previous solution, correct. So, basically i only need to replicate this layer.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -loop 1 -filter_complex "[0]setsar=1:1,format=yuva444p,drawbox=color=black@1:t=fill[vignette];[0]format=yuva444p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='st(1,pow(min(W/2,H/2),2))+st(3,pow(X-(W/2),2)+pow(Y-(H/2),2));if(lte(ld(3),ld(1)),255,0)'[circular shaped video];[vignette][circular shaped video]overlay" -filter_complex_threads 1 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -t 5 "result.mp4"`
Win version.

Comment: yuva444p and libx264 and etc are related to codecs, arent they?
So, i have two more questions, first one: Can you post like super minimal solution just for drawing the layer on top of video, without uneccesary options (if they are, i mean like i dont need convertion to another format, i just want to keep video as is (like sound bitrates, video fps, codec etc), even if process can take some time)?

Comment: The example is very minimal. You can only omit one `format=yuva444p,` in the vignette. I've edited that in the last example. The `-filter_complex` requires encoding and I assumed `libx264`  + `aac` for audio is a very common choice. You could change the av codecs but you can't omit them.

Comment: Ok, ty. Seems like this is what i need, not sure about changing encodings of original video frames or sound, but ok.I'll take a look. Also, is this expected: https://i.imgur.com/SNDFSMW.png ?

Comment: The edges are jagged. That can be fixed with antialiasing. I'll post an updated version ASAP

Comment: Thank you fore awesome answer. but I have one question. how can we make background color transparent instead of black?

Comment: I've added transparency to my answer. You need a format like `.webm` that supports transparency. If you need a different format, you can search for video formats that support an alpha channel and simply change the video codec and container.